# IdependencyResolver is always null in unit test using moq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I've implemented ninject in a mvc project and this works as expected now I'm wanting to unit test, but can't seem to get it to work:

controller:

```
 private IDependencyResolver _resolver;

 public HomeController(IDependencyResolver resolver)
 {
        _resolver = resolver;
 }

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
        var model = _resolver.GetService<ISignUpViewModel>();
        return PartialView("Login", model);
  }
```

Unit Test

```
    private IDependencyResolver _resolverMock;

    [TestMethod]
    public void SignUpTest()
    {

        var ctrl = new HomeController(_resolverMock);
        var signUpMock = new Mock<ISignUpViewModel>();

        ctrl.Index();
        ctrl.ViewData.Model = signUpMock;

        //Assert.AreEqual("", "");

    }
```

The resolver is always null.

Ive looked at Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq should I set the resolver in there?

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you ever initialize `_resolverMock`?

Comment: The reason it is null is because you never set it to be not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the unit test you manually create `HomeController` instance, So you need mock `IDependencyResolver`. For example:

```
var resolverMock = new Mock<IDependencyResolver>();
var ctrl = new HomeController(resolverMock.Object);
....
```

Comment: I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Moq.Mock<System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Great Its working now. thanks passed it as resolverMock.object.

Comment: @Tau7 Use moq can also mock some action, You can read this document:  https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Quick question:Does every interface you use in unit testing have to be mocked?

Comment: @Tau7 It's depends on you. You can set some type instance that implement the interface. But i think use moq  is better solution.